# Implementing NFC on non-NFC device

Tags: bluetooth, nfc

So I downloaded Android pay and got it setup with my card only to find that my phone doesn't have NFC. How I missed this, I don't know.

I was thinking this: could you put and NFC tag on the back of the device and somehow rig it to work? If not, would it be possible to get NFC hardware to work with a device that doesn't have it?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach external NFC readers via USB or audio port. Technically, these would not be drop-in replacements, so you'll have to go with special apps which make use of the readers.